# How come the locate command doesn't find obvious files?

Tags: locate

The locate command sounds intuitive. I would expect it to locate files on the filesystem. However, it rarely finds files on the system that are indeed present:

```
$ locate ipsec.secrets
```

This gives  no results, even when run from filesystem root directory /. The file is indeed present:

```
$ whereis ipsec.secrets
ipsec: /usr/sbin/ipsec /etc/ipsec.secrets /etc/ipsec.d /etc/ipsec.conf /usr/lib/ipsec /usr/share/man/man8/ipsec.8.gz
```

Why was locate unable to find this file?

Comment: Run updatedb and try again

Comment: After running that command with elevated privilege, then yes the file showed up. Apparently, the updatedb is updated only once a day and for new programs installed, their files will not show up yet.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`updatedb` only runs once a day, you need to run it with root privileges to find recent files.

Comment: "you need to run it with root privileges" --> i.e. `sudo updatedb`

Answer (score 10):

If you are not able to `locate` a file that *obviously exists*
I see only two possibilities:

1. The file (directory) was created after the last time that the database of locate was updated. By default it is updated once in a day (`/etc/cron.daily/mlocate`).
   With enough privilege you can fix it forcing an update  with

   ```
   sudo updatedb
   ```
2. The file (directory) was created under a path not scanned by updatedb (case more rare): you can find the keys of the *pruned files* in the configuration file `/etc/updatedb.conf`. Search for PRUNENAMES, PRUNEPATHS or PRUNEFS and modify consequently, then update again the database.

   ```
   sudo pico /etc/updatedb.conf
   sudo updatedb
   ```

Of course even without privilege you can still search for the file, for example scanning all the directories and subdirectories starting from a position with something like

```
find . -name '*ipsec.secrets*'  # to start from the current directory
find / -name '*ipsec.secrets*'  # to start from the root # long long
```

**Note** that `whereis` has a hard-coded path (where to search for), so may not always find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Being somewhat lazy and not wanting to run `sudo updatedb` and, since I have a computer that can work for me, it runs `sudo updatedb` every 15 minutes so I don't have to.

Use `sudo crontab -e` and find this line:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
```

insert below it:

```
*/15 *  *   *   *     /usr/bin/updatedb
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save the file (write it **O**ut) and then  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to e**X**it.

If you've just created the files in the last 15 minutes though you will still need to run:

```
sudo updatedb
```

... to manually update the indices used by `locate` command.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was super fast (but maybe not optimal since your `sudo updatedb` command will take more time). However, you won't miss any file anymore, even if you have multiple partitions (this is handy for me).

I opened the configuration file of `updated` (you need `sudo`  privileges to save the following file):

`nano /etc/updatedb.conf`

I then commented (adding a `#` at the beginning of the line) all the lines starting with:
`PRUNENAMES`
`PRUNEPATHS`
`PRUNEFS`

Save the file (`CTRL+O`, `ENTER`, `CTRL+X`).

I hope this helps someone else.