# nccl does not update

Tags: 16.04, package-management, upgrade, cuda, gpu

I am using ubuntu 16.04
I followed the instruction on nvidia [website](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/nccl-install-guide/index.html#down) to update nccl, after running:

```
(base) alireza@Cube1:~$ sudo apt install libnccl2 libnccl-dev
[sudo] password for alireza: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libnccl-dev is already the newest version (2.4.8-1+cuda10.0).
libnccl2 is already the newest version (2.4.8-1+cuda10.0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
(base) alireza@Cube1:~$
```

but when i want to check it via using 
`locate nccl| grep "libnccl.so" | tail -n1 | sed -r 's/^.*\.so\.//'`
I see it still shows `1` instead of `2.4.8` version.
Why is it like that?

Comment: Did you update the `locate` database? `sudo updatedb`

Comment: This solved my issue!! Thanks.
Can you make it as an answer, and also tell me what does that do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nccl` *did* update, but the database used by the `locate` command still reflects the old library file name.

You can update the `locate` database by running `sudo updatedb`. See also:

- [How come the locate command doesn't find obvious files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520963/how-come-the-locate-command-doesnt-find-obvious-files)